# Search for Object in Generic List

Tags: vb.net, generics

Is it possible to search for an object by one of its properties in a Generic List?

```
Public Class Customer

    Private _id As Integer

    Private _name As String

    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        _id = id
        _name = name
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then loading and searching

```
Dim list as new list(Of Customer)

list.Add(New Customer(1,"A")

list.Add(New Customer(2,"B")
```

How can I return customer object with id =1? Does this have to do with the "Predicate" in Generics?

Note: I am doing this in VB.NET.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this has everything to do with predicates :)

You want the [Find(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) method. You need to pass in a predicate (which is a type of delegate in this case). How you construct that delegate depends on which version of VB you're using. If you're using VB9, you could use a lambda expression. (If you're using VB9 you might want to use LINQ instead of Find(Of T) in the first place, mind you.) The lambda expression form would be something like:

```
list.Find(function(c) c.ID = 1)
```

I'm not sure if VB8 supports anonymous methods in the same way that C# 2 does though. If you need to call this from VB8, I'll see what I can come up with. (I'm more of a C# person really :)

Comment: I am using VB9 On 2.0 and not 3.5 on this project :( I'll give the lambda expression a shot. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using VB9 but restricted to .NET 2.0, you might want to look at LINQBridge: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx It's basically a LINQ to Objects implementation targeting .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

Generally you need to use predicates:

```
list.Add(New Customer(1, "A"))
list.Add(New Customer(2, "B"))

Private Function HasID1(ByVal c As Customer) As Boolean
    Return (c.ID = 1)
End Function

Dim customerWithID1 As Customer = list.Find(AddressOf HasID1)
```

Or with inline methods:

```
Dim customerWithID1 As Customer = list.Find(Function(p) p.ID = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also overload the equals method and then do a contains. like this

```
Dim list as new list(Of Customer)

list.Add(New Customer(1,"A")

list.Add(New Customer(2,"B")

list.contains(new customer(1,"A"))
```

the equals method then would look like this

```
public overrides function Equals(Obj as object) as Boolean
   return Me.Id.Equals(ctype(Obj,Customer).Id
end Function
```

Not tested but it should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5 this can be done with [LINQ to Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_Objects):

*[How to: Query an ArrayList with LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397937.aspx)*

If not, in .NET 2.0 you can use the [`Find` method of the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx).

The idea is that you will need to provide an method that return true if a property of your object satisfies a certain condition.