# Predicates and Lists

Tags: c#, list, predicate, findall

I have a generic list.

Some elements of this list belong to a parent element. I retrieved all these elements from a database and i want to recursively build a tree with them.

So, here's what i'm thinking:

Here is my predicate:

```
public static bool FindChildren(Int32 parentId,CategoryMapping catMapping)
{
    if (catMapping.parentId == parentId)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

root = list[0];
root.childrenElements = root.FindAll(FindChildren(root.id,???)
```

I can't figure out how this would work. How can i do this kind of predicate?

PS: I'm using VS2005 :(

Comment: @George: In case you didn't know, you can just `return catMapping.parentId == parentId`, you don't need the if/else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
root.childrenElements = 
    root
       .Where( i => i.parentId == yourCatMapping.parentId)
       .ToArray();
```

EDIT

In .net 2.0 I think it is

```
root.FindAll(
    delegate(CategoryMapping mapping)
        {
             return mapping.parentId == root.Id;
        });
```

Comment: Asker is on .net 2.0, and therefore doesn't have linq

Comment: @Binary Worrier: the PS of the question is recent ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a delegate to pass to `FindAll`, rather than a direct function call

(assuming `root` is `List<CategoryMapping>`)

```
root.childrenElements = root.FindAll(c => FindChildren(root.id, c));
```

Comment: George is using VS 2005, so a lambda expression won't work. He needs to use the `delegate` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this thread that I started on [Forming good predicate delegates to Find() or FindAll() in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242012/how-do-i-form-a-good-predicate-delegate-to-find-something-in-my-listt) for C# / .NET 2.0

It answers your question pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Gregoire's answer is the best, because it:

1. Doesn't use LINQ (the asker is using VS 2005)
2. Doesn't use a lambda expression (again, VS 2005)

That said, why not make things (slightly) easier for yourself by writing a function to generate your `Predicate` **for** you:

```
public static Predicate<CategoryMapping> GetIsChildOf(int parentId) {
    return delegate(CategoryMapping cm) {
        return cm.parentId == parentId;
    };
}
```

Then if you have a `List<CategoryMapping>` and you want to find all elements with a certain `parentId` property, you can just call:

```
root = list[0];
root.childrenElements = list.FindAll(GetIsChildOf(root.id));
```

Comment: great post dan. it cleared some things for me. Thanks all of you! SO is great. Thanks a lot guys, i was going crazy on this.