# ASP.NET / VB.NET - Get parameter by name from MySqlParameter list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary, collections, sqlparameter

I'm passing a method a list of MySqlParameters as follows:

```
ByVal Params As List(Of MySqlParameter)
```

If I have multiple parameters in this list and I want to check the value of a particular one, how can I get a reference to that parameter by `ParameterName`?

I know I can make it work passing a `Dictionary` or some other `Collection`, but I just wanted to know if there is a way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Params.Find(Function(x) x.ParameterName = "MyParam")
```

Found at: [Search for Object in Generic List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200151/search-for-object-in-generic-list)