# How to change a value in list of class?

Tags: vb.net, list, class

Given a class like so

```
Public Class ItemPanel

    Inherits Panel

    Public Name as string
    Public Quantity As Integer

End Class
```

And a list like so

```
Public li_ip As New List(Of ItemPanel)
```

I have a sub will help me add ItemPanel to li_ip list when a button clicked, every button clicked will also add their text into li_item, so when a button click twice, only the first time will add ItemPanel to li_ip, second click will only change the quantity in ItemPanel

```
Private Sub RefreshOrdered(sender As Object)
        If Not li_item.Contains(sender.Text) Then

            Dim pn As ItemPanel
            With pn
                .Name = sender.Text
                .Quantity = 1
            End With

            li_ip.Add(pn)

        Else

            'Here I want to change the quantity in ItemPanel depend on the sender.Text

        End If
End Sub
```

So how can I get the result I want? What should I write after else?

Comment: To get the item from the list this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/200165/5152045

Comment: Seems to me like you want a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`. Have you checked containers other than `List`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To search for an `list item` by one of its properties the [List(Of T).Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)  can be used. In this case the List is referenced by variable `li_ip` and the property which is used to find the `list item` is the `Name`.

According to the MSDN documentation the `Find` method returns *the first* element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the *default value for type T*.

Default value of T which is `ItemPanel` is `Nothing` becasue `ItemPanel` is a reference type. So when `Find` actually finds the `item` then its `Quantity` can be incremented. HTH

```
Dim itm As ItemPanel = li_ip.Find(function(c) c.Name = sender.Text)
If Not itm Is Nothing Then
    itm.Quantity = itm.Quantity + 1   
End If
```

> Complete code could look like this.

```
Private Sub RefreshOrdered(sender As Object)
    ' Notice that Contains like this won't work:
    If Not li_ip.Contains(sender.Text) Then

        Dim pn As ItemPanel
        ' shouldn't here the New keyword be used?
        ' pn = New ItemPanel()  
        With pn
            .Name = sender.Text
            .Quantity = 1
        End With

        li_ip.Add(pn)

    Else

        'Here I want to change the quantity in ItemPanel depend on the sender.Text
        Dim itm As ItemPanel = li_ip.Find(function(c) c.Name = sender.Text)
        If Not itm Is Nothing Then
            itm.Quantity = itm.Quantity + 1   
        End If 

    End If
End Sub
```

*Note:* LINQ can be used as well, but maybe `Find` is faster. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault).

---

EDIT:

Here is refactored version where the method `Find` is called just once like @Default has mentioned.

```
Private Sub RefreshOrdered(sender As Object)
    Dim panelName As string = sender.Text
    Dim panel As ItemPanel = li_ip.Find(function(p) p.Name = panelName) 
    If Not panel Is Nothing Then
        ' Panel with given name exists already in list, increment Quantity
        panel.Quantity += 1   
    Else 
        ' Panel with such name doesn't exist in list yet, add new one with this name
        Dim newPanel As ItemPanel
        newPanel = New ItemPanel()  
        With newPanel
            .Name = panelName
            .Quantity = 1
        End With
        li_ip.Add(newPanel)
    End If 
End Sub
```

Alternatively `LINQ` can be used instaed of `Find`, e.g. like this:

```
Dim panel As ItemPanel = li_ip.SingleOrDefault(function(p) p.Name = panelName)
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining *why* you used that code?

Comment: maybe you should call `Find` first and check if the returned value is `null`. Right now you are traversing the list twice (once with `.Contains` and then with `.Find`), which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Default yes you are absolutely right! I just wanted to answer the question in the way it was build. But yes, the code could be refactored this way.